# Giving explicit map for Strong Deformation Retraction

Tags: algebraic-topology

One of the exercise says that $\mathbb{S^1}×1 \cup 1×\mathbb{S^1}$ is strong deformation retraction of $\mathbb{S^1} × \mathbb{S^1} - (-1,-1) $. My intuitive understanding was $\mathbb{S^1} × \mathbb{S^1} - (-1,-1) $ is similar to $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{S^1}×1 \cup 1×\mathbb{S^1}$ is same as like union of lines x=1 and y=1. so pictorially I have got the intuition behind this. But I can't come up with explicit map. Any help. Here 1 is (1,0) and -1 is (-1,0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometrically, $S^1\times\{1\}\cup\{1\}\times S^1\cong S^1\vee S^1$, and $S^1\times S^1\setminus\{(-1,-1)\}$ is the punctured torus ($=T^2\setminus \{p\}\cong([-1,1]^2/\sim)\setminus\{p\}$).

I think this is what you want:

Let $p=(-1,-1)$, $I=[-1,1]$ and $(s_1,s_2)\in (I^2/\sim)\setminus\{p\}$  then we construct the deformation retraction $H:(I^2/\sim)\setminus\{p\}\times[0,1]\to (s_1\times\{1\}\cup \{1\}\times s_2)/\sim$ by:
$$
H(s_1,s_2,t)=
\begin{cases}
(t(\frac{2(s_1+1)}{|s_2+1|}-1-s_1)+s_1, (1-s_2)t+s_2)& \text{if }s_2\ge s_1\\
((1-s_1)t+s_1, t(\frac{2(s_2+1)}{|s_1+1|}-1-s_2)+s_2)& \text{if }s_2\le s_1
\end{cases}
$$

The map is well-defined and continuous at both branches.

A way to visualize this map is to think about the square under the quotient $\sim$, because in this case, $\frac{s_1\times\{1\}\cup \{1\}\times s_2}{\sim}\cong S^1\times\{1\}\cup\{1\}\times S^1$. $H$ expands the hole created by $\{p\}$ (in the left corner) and maps every point in $T^2\setminus\{p\}$ to the two edges that have one point in common by sliding each point linearly through the line between $(-1,-1)$ and the two edges which is obviously **equal** to the space indicated in the first sentence. ("the two edges" means $\frac{s_1\times\{1\}\cup \{1\}\times s_2}{\sim}$)

The space $\frac{s_1\times\{1\}\cup \{1\}\times s_2}{\sim}$ is the same as $S^1\times\{1\}\cup\{1\}\times S^1$ because $\sim$ generates the equivalence relation which states that $(s_1,1)\sim(s_1,-1),(1,s_2)\sim(-1,s_2)\implies (-1,1)\sim (1,1)\sim (1,-1)$ which implies that the two edges are actually two circles. After identification, we see that only $(1,1)$ belongs to both circles simultaneously so this is also equivalent to the wedge sum of two circles, namely $S^1\vee S^1$. (hope this makes it clearer...)

---

If there is anything ambiguous, please tell me and I'll try to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

$S^1 \times S^1$ is homeomorphic to $\left[-1, 1\right]^2 / \sim$ where $\left(x,-1\right) \sim \left(x, 1\right), \left(-1,y\right) \sim \left(1, y\right)$. There is a deformation retract of $\left[-1,1\right]^2-\left(0,0\right)$ onto $\partial\left[-1,1\right]$ that fixes the boundary, and in particular well defined also after quotiening by $\sim$. This will give you the desired deformation retract.